# php array push - associative arrays and keep associative keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have several associative arrays, each starting with a string key.  I also have a master array that i want to use to combine each of these sub arrays.  When using array_push though, each array is then given an additional numeric key in the master array.

How can i avoid this and push the sub arrays into the master array keeping the keys intact?

Comment: Hum? If you push the subarrays into the master array you won't change the subarrays.

Comment: No, the subarrays are intact but each is then given a nmumerical key in the master array.  The subarrays are structured so that the first element is an array.  This elements key is an id.  I want this key to be kept intact and used in the master array.  When using array_push or shift i am getting this extra layer that i dont want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$master_array = array_merge($master_array, $sub_array_1, $sub_array_2, ...) ;
```

Beware of what happens when the sub arrays have the same keys - if they are numeric, you will get both values, but if not, later values will over-write earlier ones.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted any example, it is difficult for me to visualize you code... however, I think you need to use "array_merge" function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Hope that helped.